Access the Google Translate "see dictionary" link via Google Translate API
When using  Google Translate via translate.google.com, after entering a word to be translated, a "See Dictionary" link appears. Clicking the link opens a panel with more details of that word. Is it possible to access the data in this panel via the Google Translate API?

